# Canceling query with while loop hangs forever

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, async-await, cancellation

I am trying to use query cancellation (via cancellation tokens) to cancel a long-running complex query. I have found that in some cases not only does cancellation fail to halt the query but also the call to `CancellationToken.Cancel()` hangs indefinitely. Here is a simple repro that replicates this behavior (can be run in LinqPad):

```
void Main()
{   
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var blocked = RunSqlAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    blocked.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Dump(); // false (blocked in SQL as expected)
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel(); // hangs forever?!
    Console.WriteLine("Finished calling Cancel()");
    blocked.Wait();
}

public async Task RunSqlAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = @".\sqlexpress", IntegratedSecurity = true, Pooling = false }.ConnectionString;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = @"
                WHILE 1 = 1
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @x INT = 1
                END
            ";
            command.CommandTimeout = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Running query");
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Interestingly, the same query run in SqlServer Management Studio cancels instantly via the "Cancel Executing Query" button.

Is there some caveat to query cancellation where it cannot cancel tight WHILE loops?

My version of SqlServer:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
>       Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
>       Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>       Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: )

I am running on Windows 10, and .NET's `Environment.Version` is 4.0.30319.42000.

**EDIT**

Some additional information:

Here is the stack trace pulled from Visual Studio when `cancellationToken.Cancel()` hangs:

[image: Cancel() stack trace]

Another thread is stuck here:

[image: ExecuteNonQueryAsync() stack trace]

Additionally, I tried updating to SqlServer Express 2017 and I am seeing the same behavior.

**EDIT**

I've filed this as a bug with corefx: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26623

Comment: I will be more worried about the `WHILE LOOP` in my SQL, why it hangs is a smaller issue.

Comment: Most likely SqlServer Management Studio doesn't use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` and so its quite possible it is able to cancel queries immediately by other means

Comment: How realistic is it to have an infinite loop that doesn't return anything anyway?   You could always try adding a command timeout

Comment: @M.Ali I am showing a toy case here to try to track down a technical limitation or bug. I actually think that having query cancellation hang is quite a large issue. Imagine if one were trying to implement an SSMS-like tool on top of ADO.NET? This would be a big problem.

Comment: @MickyD a command timeout will cause the query to exit, but only after the timeout expires. In my use-case it is appropriate for the timeout to be quite long, and so I am relying on cancellation to abort the query before that point if the operation ends up not being needed. Again in the real case the loop is not truly infinite but takes sufficiently long to terminate under some conditions that this problem is noticeable.

Comment: Is this really being run in a console app? Or is there a sync context? Can you pause the debugger during the hang and post the full stack of the cancelling thread including external code? This often exposes interesting internal function names.

Comment: @usr I've hit this both when running unit tests through visual studio and via LinqPad. In VS the stack trace suggests that the call to `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` is stuck in the method `TdsParserStateObject.Cancel()`

Comment: That part of the stack is probably not enough, and it is not necessary for me to guess when I could be looking at a full stack. Please make a screenshot of the call stack window.

Comment: @usr I've added full stack traces to the post itself.

Comment: Good. This looks like a bug in ADO.NET to me. Is your .NET version current? According to my decompiler there is no TPSO.Cancel() method. I'm on the latest .NET. Maybe patching will solve this issue since there seem to be code changes at exactly this location.

Comment: @usr I targeted .NET 4.7.1 and added a call to the new RuntimeFeature class (introduced in that version) just to be sure it was definitely running. I see the same behavior with the hang in TPSO.Cancel() as the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue in a console application. (The code in the question was code from LINQPad.)

I'm going to make this an answer and say that this is a bug in ADO.NET. ADO.NET should send a query cancellation signal to SQL Server. I can see from the CPU usage, that SQL Server continues executing the loop. Therefore, it did not receive cancellation from the client. We also know that SSMS is able to cancel this loop.

While the loop is running I can see that the console app is using 50% of one CPU core and receiving data from SQL Server at 70MB/sec. I do not know what data this is. It might be ROWCOUNT information or something related.

I think the bug is related to the fact that the loop is continuously sending data so that ADO.NET never has an opportunity to send the cancellation. It's still a bug and it would be a community service if you reported it. You can link to this question.

If the loop is throttled using ...

```
            WHILE 1 = 1
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @x INT = 1
                WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01' --new
            END
```

... then cancellation is quick.

Also, you can generally not rely on cancellation being quick. If the network dropped it might take 30sec for the client to notice this and throw.

Therefore you need to code your program so that it continues executing and not wait for the query to finish. It could look like this:

```
var queryTask = ...;
var cancellationToken = ...;

await Task.WhenAll(queryTask, cancellationToken);
```

That way cancellation always *looks* instantaneous. Make sure that resources are still disposed. All SQL interaction should be encapsulated in `queryTask` so that it simply continues in the background and eventually cleans up.

Comment: This is correct. I've filed the bug with MSFT here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26623